# Expand Background Color of a Sidebar Relation to Main Content Section

Tags: css, html, background-color

I am trying to get my sidebar background color till the bottom of the page but I can't. Also, when the main content height will increase the sidebar should expand on same height. The bottom logo should always remain at the bottom of the wrapper. How can I achieve this goal?

Example snapshot could be found here: http://s14.postimg.org/dzai5m0mp/screenshot_2014_04_30.png

I tried to give the aside height:100% but no luck.

Please have a look and Any help is appreciated, Cheers

Comment: Please include your relevant code rather than a snapshot

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your comments. Since I am using twitter bootstrap, I couldn't show the codes in jsfiddle.  I have uploaded the files that can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76890716/stackoverflow/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is any Class or ID placed on your main sidebar div. In css give that property`clear:both;` and `height 100%;` and `display:table-cell;`. it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

http://jsfiddle.net/Fgz95/1/

All parents elements that are inside the element you want to be 100% height must have 100% height (including html and body tags).

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```